# How to build sibling aggregations using the Elasticsearch Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to do a filter aggregation, nested aggregation, and then 3 sibling aggregations. I have tested this and it works using the REST API. Here is the query I used:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filter_agg": {
      "filter": {
        ...
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_agg": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "myProperty"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sibling_agg_1": {
              ...
            },
            "sibling_agg_2": {
              ...
            },
            "sibling_agg_3": {
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to implement this query using the Java APIs in my codebase. I am not sure how to do sibling aggregations, as the only method available to the `FilterAggregationBuilder` is `subAggregation()`.

In the context of the Java API is are these sibling aggregations sub aggregations?

The Java code I have started to write looks like this:

```
client.prepareSearch(index)
    .setTypes(types)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.COUNT)
    .addAggregation(myFilterAggregation
      .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.nested("nested_agg").path("myProperty"))
```

and then the only thing I can continue to do to build the `SearchRequestBuilder` is more `subAggregation`'s - is that the correct way to implement this? The REST API and Java API seem different in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this by adding sub-aggregation to the `nested` one (note that I chose a `terms` aggregation since it wasn't clear from your query DSL what specific aggregation type you're using as the sibling aggregations):

```
// create the nested aggregation
NestedBuilder nestedAgg = AggregationBuilders.nested("nested_agg").path("myProperty");

// now add each of your sub-aggregation to it
nestedAgg.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("sibling_agg_1").field("field1"));
nestedAgg.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("sibling_agg_2").field("field2"));
nestedAgg.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("sibling_agg_3").field("field3"));

// finally add the nested aggregation to the filter aggregation
client.prepareSearch(index)
    .setTypes(types)
    .setSearchType(SearchType.COUNT)
    .addAggregation(myFilterAggregation
      .subAggregation(nestedAgg);
```

Comment: Yes, what I realized yesterday is that it depends on what you call subAggregation on to determine if it is a child or sibling aggregation.